# Has or have usage with this particular sentence

Tags: grammatical-number, tense-agreement

> If any of Canadian publishers already **have/has** the rights for this book?

Which one is correct or both are possible?

Answer (score 0):

If any of Canadian publishers already have/has the rights for this book?

**Correct question with the verb have**:

**Do** any Canadian publishers **alread**y have the rights for this book?

Do you have x?, Do they have x?, Does he/she/it have x?.

Comment: It could also be "Does any Canadian publisher already have..."

Comment: I showed plural and singular question forms with have. The point is that the OP did not know how to pose a question with the right verb form regardless of plural or singular.

Answer (score -1):

**any Canadian publishers** is a plural noun, so you should use the plural verb **have**. However the 'of' is incorrect - the sentence should read

> If any Canadian publishers already have the rights for this book

It shouldn't have a question mark either, as that sentence by itself can't be a question.

Answer (score -1):

First off, your sentence is a fragment, since there's a dependent clause ("If...") without a main clause.

If you want to rewrite the dependent clause, it could be either of the following:

> If any Canadian publishers already have the rights for this book...
>
> If any Canadian publisher already has the rights for this book...

It's more likely to be the second one, since only one publisher typically holds the rights to a book at any one time.

Notice that it should be "any Canadian publishers" instead of "any of Canadian publishers", as @otoh007 pointed out.

Comment: Why the downvote? If this answer is incorrect, I'd like to know why.

Comment: I'm equally puzzled by the downvote. It would be a good idea if downvoters were required to give a reason, even if this meant identifying themselves.